# RecyclerView scrolls to top every time ContentProvider calls getContentResolver.notifyChange(uri, observer=null)?

Tags: android, view

I have a `RecyclerView` that contains a `ListView`, and every time the back end database changes (via the update() method in the `ContentProvider`), the `ContentProvider` calls `getContext()`.`getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null)`, which makes the `RecyclerView` scroll to top.

I understand that if we are updating the view in the adapter, we can just call `notifyDatasetChanged()` and then smooth scroll to the current position in the activity. But since I've already been only calling `notifyDatasetChanged()` in the Adapter, and this problem is caused the `notifyChange()` in the `ContentProvider`, does anyone have an idea how to solve it?

Also I have a `LoaderManager` in my Activity, and no `ContentObserver` is needed.

Comment: try to clear focus on recycler view